# Is it possible to get type of an assembly .net 4.0 from .net 3.5 project?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a type of some Microsoft .net 4.0 dll from .net 3.5 project. Don't wont to load them since I know that is impossible with Assembly.Load or LoadFrom. Only thing I need is Type. Is this possible and how to do it? For example this is dll ADONETSrc that I am trying get Type is:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ADONETSrc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91.
```

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK Without loading you can't get a `Type`

Comment: Could you explain what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: My goal is to load through reflection some fields and methods from that .net 4.0 dll.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. Loading a .net 4.0 type requires loading CLR engine v4.0, which can't be loaded by the .NET 2.0 CLR engine.

Answer (score 2):

Chicked-and-egg question. Anything you could possibly do with the type requires the program to run with the v4 version of the CLR. Simple to do with a .config file, `<supportedRuntime>` element. At which point loading the assembly isn't a problem anymore either.

As originally stated: no, the metadata format was changed in .NET 4.0.  The v2 CLR simply doesn't know how read it and will refuse to do so, throwing a BadImageFormatException.  Type info is stored in the assembly metadata so you can never get to it.

Comment: Yes, tried that and that works fine. But the problem is sometimes exception unexpected happen when this line is defined. Ok, thanks everyone for helping me with this one.